# Simplify Log monotonicity

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Why does:

```
FullSimplify[(n+1)^2>n^2,n>=2]
```

evaluate to `True`, but:

```
FullSimplify[Log[n+1]>Log[n],n>=2]
```

remains unchanged?

Thank you.

Comment: `Reduce[{Log[n + 1] > Log[n], n >=2}]`.

Comment: `Resolve[ForAll[n, n >= 1, Log[n + 1] > Log[n]]]`

Comment: Okay, thank you both.
Should it be obvious to me why `FullSimplify` works for the one, and not the other? And why `Reduce` succeeds with both?
Do you in general shy away from `FullSimply`, in favor of `Reduce`?
Asked differently: why would `Resolve` all of a sudden be necessary?
Perhaps the key is that `FullSimplify` is pattern matching, whereas the other two are performing mathematical reduction/resolution?
Thanx.

Comment: Well, Simplify is supposed to "simplify" an expression. Typically gives one with smaller leaf size. I am not sure it is supposed/required to return "True" or "False", even though it did that on the first example you gave it. That is why Reduce is there.  Looking at help, I see no place where it says it will return "True" or "False" for inequality relation?  May be for one that are "easy" to figure out, it return True or False and that is why it worked on your first example.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to:

```
Resolve[ForAll[n, n >= 1, Log[n + 1] > Log[n]]]
```

You can try:

```
FullSimplify[Log[n + 1] > Log[n], n >= 1, 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, Exp}]
```

> True

Comment: Since `Exp[expr]` is not equivalent to `expr`, I don't think I'd count it as a valid transformation. We could really take a short cut and use `TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, True &}` in this case. :)

Comment: I guess this is okay: `TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, # /. r : _Greater :> ApplySides[Exp, r] &}`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, thank you all for your input. I think the simplest approach for obtaining `True` is:

```
FullSimplify[Reduce[Log[n + 1] > Log[n], n], n >= 2]
```

i.e., allowing `Reduce` to do its mathematical reduction, and then `FullSimplify` "cleans up" with the assumptions. In (slightly?) more complex cases, `Reduce` may require the assumption as part of the list of expressions.

Answer (score 3):

As @Nasser mentioned in a comment, simplification in Mathematica tries to minimize the "complexity" of an expression, which is predominantly measured by `LeafCount[]`. There are two difficulties with `Full/Simplify`: First, they have only a finite set of transformation functions available and a needed transformation may be missing. Second, they limit how far down rabbit trails they are willing to go in seeking a simpler expression.  Consequently, as a discrete global minimization problem, one is not guaranteed to find the minimum.

One can add transformation functions, and if a `Simplify` is thrown into them, it might take the search further down a trail toward the minimum.

```
FullSimplify[Log[n + 1] > Log[n], n >= 2, 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic,
   # /. r : _Greater :> Simplify[SubtractSides[r, Last@r], n >= 2] &}]
(*  True  *)
```

If you throw in `echo = (Print[#1]; #1) &` as a `TransformationFunction`, you see some (maybe all) the expressions that are transformed.  While both the OP's `FullSimplify` and mine try `Log[1 + 1/n]`, only mine tries `Log[1 + 1/n] > 0` (within the `Simplify[]` transformation function).  And that makes the difference.